# Calling new Runnable() crashes on Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runnable, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I've met some problem with creating Runnable() on Android devices with API24 and API25 (Android Nougat). In summary I'm trying to do something like that:

```
MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myTask.executeTask(new AsyncTaskListener() {
@Override
public void onTaskFinished(Object result) {
    try {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Test", "Hello Runnable");
            }
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("Test", "Exception");
    }
}
});
```

On API earlier than 24 everything works properly, but on API24 and 25 I'm catching exception:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isAnonymousClass()' on a null object reference
```

Any ideas, hint or suggestions how can resolve this problem?

**Edit**

Complete callstack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isAnonymousClass()' on a null object reference
                  at hugo.weaving.internal.Hugo.asTag(Hugo.java:97)
                  at hugo.weaving.internal.Hugo.asTag(Hugo.java:98)
                  at hugo.weaving.internal.Hugo.enterMethod(Hugo.java:71)
                  at hugo.weaving.internal.Hugo.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$hugo_weaving_internal_Hugo$hugo_weaving_internal_Hugo$enterMethod(Hugo.java:1)
                  at hugo.weaving.internal.Hugo.logAndExecute(Hugo.java:36)
                  at my.app.MainFragmentActivity$9$1.<init>(MainFragmentActivity.java:918)
                  at my.app.MainFragmentActivity$9.onTaskFinished_aroundBody2(MainFragmentActivity.java:918)
                  at my.app.MainFragmentActivity$9$AjcClosure3.run(MainFragmentActivity.java:1)
                  at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
                  at hugo.weaving.internal.Hugo.logAndExecute(Hugo.java:39)
                  at my.app.MainFragmentActivity$9.onTaskFinished(MainFragmentActivity.java:914)
                  at my.app.module.net.WhoIsOnlineAsyncTask.onPostExecute(WhoIsOnlineAsyncTask.java:78)
                  at my.app.module.net.WhoIsOnlineAsyncTask.onPostExecute(WhoIsOnlineAsyncTask.java:19)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Line:

```
 at my.app.MainFragmentActivity$9$1.<init>(MainFragmentActivity.java:918)
```

pointing to the line when I'm creating Runnable instance. I don't event execute created Runnable. In above code I've removed as many as I can to figure out which line is causing problem with crash.

Comment: You're not calling that `Runnable`.  Is this your actual code?

Comment: Beyond that, please post the entire Java stack trace, along with the code that generated it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede no at this moment I also removed code to calling created instance of Runnable. Creating instance of this object cause crash.

Comment: @Grzegorz I'm pretty sure you're mistaken.  Please post the real code and indicate which is line 78.

Comment: Create a reproducible scenario and file a bug against [the Hugo project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo), I guess. Hugo is crashing, not your code directly.